# What Am I Missing When Parsing this JSON Output

Tags: python, json

What am I missing when trying to parse this JSON output with Python?  The JSON looks like this:

```
    {
  "start": 0,
  "terms": [
    "process_name:egagent.exe"
  ],
  "highlights": [],
  "total_results": 448,
  "filtered": {},
  "facets": {},
  "results": [
    {
      "username": "SYSTEM",
      "alert_type": "test"
    },
    {
      "username": "SYSTEM2",
      "alert_type": "test"
    }
   ]
  }
```

The Python I'm trying to use to access this is simple.  I want to grab username, but everything I try throws an error.  When it doesn't throw an error, I seem to get the letter of each one.  So, if I do:

```
apirequest = requests.get(requesturl, headers=headers, verify=False)
readable = json.loads(apirequest.content)

#print readable
for i in readable:
    print (i[0])
```

I get s, t, h, t, f, f, r, which are the first letters of each item.  If I try i[1], I get the second letter of each item.  When I try by name, say, i["start"], I get an error saying the string indices must be integers.  I'm pretty confused and I am new to Python, but I haven't found anything on this yet.  Please help!  I just want to access the username fields, which is why I am trying to do the for loop.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you iterate over a dictionary, you will get the keys, only. Try `for key, value in readable.items():`!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16129667/5922757

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in readable["results"]:
    print i["username"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Load your json string:

```
import json

s = """
{
  "start": 0,
  "terms": [
    "process_name:egagent.exe"
  ],
  "highlights": [],
  "total_results": 448,
  "filtered": {},
  "facets": {},
  "results": [
    {
      "username": "SYSTEM",
      "alert_type": "test"
    },
    {
      "username": "SYSTEM2",
      "alert_type": "test"
    }
   ]
}
"""
```

And print username for every result:

```
print [res['username'] for res in json.loads(s)['results']]
```

Output:

```
[u'SYSTEM', u'SYSTEM2']
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in readable` will iterate `i` through each key in the `readable` dictionary. If you then print `i[0]`, you are printing the first character of each key.

Given that you want the values associated with the `"username"` key in the entries of the list which is associated with the `"results"` key, you can get them like this:

```
for result in readable["results"]:
     print (result["username"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `readable` is your JSON object (`dict`), you can access elements like you'd in every map, using their keys.

```
readable["results"][0]["username"]
```

Should give you `"SYSTEM"` string as result.

To print every username, do:

```
for result in readable["results"]:
    print(result["username"])
```

If your JSON is a `str` object, you have to [deserialize it with `json.loads(readable)` first](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html).

Comment: Thanks!  I am able to get it now, but it's limiting me to a certain number.  There should be 400 or so in that output, but i'm only seeing like 10.  How should I adjust the for loop to parse through each username in each result to grab each one?  I've added an iterator and it's being added to on each loop, but it only grabs 10 or so.  So I have for i in readable: print (readable["results"][count]["username"]) count +=1

Comment: You'd have to show us some more code (not the whole JSON of course, you can replace too many objects with `...`). It shouldn't matter how many `results` you've got.