# Python returning key value pair from JSON object

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to return the 'publisher' and 'title' values of the first entry in this JSON object.

```
{
    "count": 30,
    "recipes": [{
        "publisher": "Closet Cooking",
        "f2f_url": "htt//food2forkcom/view/35171",
        "title": "Buffalo Chicken Grilled Cheese Sandwich",
        "source_url": "htt//wwwclosetcookingcom/2011/08/buffalo-chicken-grilled-cheese-sandwich.html",
        "recipe_id": "35171",
        "image_url": "htt//staticfood2forkcom/Buffalo2BChicken2BGrilled2BCheese2BSandwich2B5002B4983f2702fe4.jpg",
        "social_rank": 100.0,
        "publisher_url": "htt//closetcooking.com"
    }, {
        "publisher": "All Recipes",
        "f2f_url": "htt//food2fork.com/view/29159",
        "title": "Slow Cooker Chicken Tortilla Soup",
        "source_url": "htt//allrecipescom/Recipe/Slow-Cooker-Chicken-Tortilla-Soup/Detail.aspx",
        "recipe_id": "29159",
        "image_url": "htt//staticfood2forkcom/19321150c4.jpg",
        "social_rank": 100.0,
        "publisher_url": "htt//allrecipescom"
    }]
}
```

When I run this code, i can return  the object minus the count part at the start.

```
r = requests.post(url, data = {"key":"aeee9034f8d624f0e6c57fe08e2fd406","q":"chicken"})
recipe=r.json()
print(recipe['recipes'])
```

However when I try to run:

```
print(recipe['recipes']['publisher'])
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What should I be doing in my code to print the information:

```
Closet Cooking, Bacon Wrapped Jalapeno Popper Stuffed Chicken
```

Comment: The inner dict is embedded in a list: `recipe['recipes'][0]['publisher']`

Comment: Realize that `recipe['recipes']` will now be a *list*, so you need to treat it as such by accessing the value by its *index*. The generic way to do this, would be to iterate, in the event you *do* have multiple values in that list. But, the first comment indicating to use `[0]` will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129652/accessing-json-elements

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

`recipe['recipes']` is a list of objects, thus you can iterate over it:

To return the 'publisher' and 'title' values of the first entry in this JSON object you can use list comprehension and get the first element of the resulting collection:

```
recipes = [{element['publisher']: element['title']} for element in recipe['recipes']][0]
```

This gives you a bit of flexibility if you want to expand the result and include more fields, or more elements in the returned list.

Answer (score -1):

The `'recipes'` key contains a list of multiple recipes

```
recipe['recipes'][0]['publisher']
```

will return the publisher of the first recipe in the list.

Comment: Maybe you can use that shiny gold hammer to dupe this question. :)