# How can I access the nested data in this complex JSON, which includes another JSON document as one of the strings?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have some JSON data like:

```
{
  "status": "200",
  "msg": "",
  "data": {
    "time": "1515580011",
    "video_info": [
      {
          "announcement": "{\"announcement_id\":\"6\",\"name\":\"INS\\u8d26\\u53f7\",\"icon\":\"http:\\\/\\\/liveme.cms.ksmobile.net\\\/live\\\/announcement\\\/2017-08-18_19:44:54\\\/ins.png\",\"icon_new\":\"http:\\\/\\\/liveme.cms.ksmobile.net\\\/live\\\/announcement\\\/2017-10-20_22:24:38\\\/4.png\",\"videoid\":\"15154610218328614178\",\"content\":\"FOLLOW ME PLEASE\",\"x_coordinate\":\"0.22\",\"y_coordinate\":\"0.23\"}",
          "announcement_shop": "",
```

etc.

How do I grab the content `"FOLLOW ME PLEASE"`? I tried using

```
replay_data = raw_replay_data['data']['video_info'][0]
announcement = replay_data['announcement']
```

But now `announcement` is a string representing more JSON data. I can't continue indexing `announcement['content']` results in `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

How can I get the desired string in the "right" way, i.e. respecting the actual structure of the data?

Comment: I reopened the question after some fixes; it is not a proper duplicate, since it specifically deals with the question of interpreting nested JSON data *as a string that needs to be re-parsed*. Most of the questions that were originally closed as a duplicate of this, should be duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788217/how-to-extract-a-single-value-from-json-response instead; I will edit them.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In a single line -

```
>>> json.loads(data['data']['video_info'][0]['announcement'])['content']
'FOLLOW ME PLEASE'
```

---

To help you understand how to access data (so you don't have to ask again), you'll need to *stare at your data*.

First, let's lay out your data nicely. You can either use `json.dumps(data, indent=4)`, or you can use an online tool like [JSONLint.com](https://jsonlint.com).

```
{
    'data': {
        'time': '1515580011',
        'video_info': [{
            'announcement': (    # ***
            """{
                "announcement_id": "6",
                "name": "INS\\u8d26\\u53f7",
                "icon": "http:\\\\/\\\\/liveme.cms.ksmobile.net\\\\/live\\\\/announcement\\\\/2017-08-18_19:44:54\\\\/ins.png",
                "icon_new": "http:\\\\/\\\\/liveme.cms.ksmobile.net\\\\/live\\\\/announcement\\\\/2017-10-20_22:24:38\\\\/4.png",
                "videoid": "15154610218328614178",
                "content": "FOLLOW ME PLEASE",
                "x_coordinate": "0.22",
                "y_coordinate": "0.23"
            }"""),
            'announcement_shop': ''
        }]
    },
    'msg': '',
    'status': '200'
}
```

*** Note that the data in the `announcement` key is actually *more* json data, which I've laid out on separate lines.

First, find out where your data resides. You're looking for the data in the `content` key, which is accessed by the `announcement` key, which is part of a dictionary inside a list of dicts, which can be accessed by the `video_info` key, which is in turn accessed by `data`.

So, in summary, "descend" the ladder that is "data" using the following "rungs" -

1. `data`, a dictionary
2. `video_info`, a list of dicts
3. `announcement`, a dict in the first dict of the list of dicts
4. `content` residing as part of json data.

---

First,

```
i = data['data']
```

Next,

```
j = i['video_info']
```

Next,

```
k = j[0] # since this is a list
```

If you only want the first element, this suffices. Otherwise, you'd need to *iterate*:

```
for k in j:
    ...
```

Next,

```
l = k['announcement']
```

Now, `l` is JSON data. Load it -

```
import json
m = json.loads(l)
```

Lastly,

```
content = m['content']
```

```
print(content)
'FOLLOW ME PLEASE'
```

This should hopefully serve as a guide should you have future queries of this nature.

Comment: How can we handle null cases here efficiently . Suppose if no m['content'] is present in JSON

Comment: @JibinMathew I'd imagine something along the lines of a try-except AttributeError or if block should be more than enough.

Comment: I created this method for helper. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129652/accessing-json-elements/66275899#66275899

Answer (score 3):

You have *nested JSON data*; the string associated with the `'annoucement'` key is itself another, separate, embedded JSON document.

You'll have to decode that string first:

```
import json

replay_data = raw_replay_data['data']['video_info'][0]
announcement = json.loads(replay_data['announcement'])
print(announcement['content'])
```

then handle the resulting dictionary from there.

Answer (score -2):

The content of `"announcement"` is another JSON string. Decode it and then access its contents as you were doing with the outer objects.

Comment: @IgncioVazquez-Abrams  Can you provide a code example?