# Fetch multi level JSON data using python

Tags: python, json, api

The json is at:

https://pastebin.com/ZDQESKcX

This is my JSON response, i want to fetch the label value in address field using python(response>>view>>result>>location>>address>label), i need to print this label field value on the consol, please help,
i have used this method :

I Tried:

```
response_data=data['Response']['View']['Result'][0]['Location']['Address']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View` is an array, you need to index it.

```
response_data = data['Response']['View'][0]['Result'][0]['Location']['Address']
```

Comment: if i want to print some value from Result section, should this directory works??

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193502/access-a-particular-field-in-arbitrarily-nested-json-data for the general principles of accessing nested JSON data.