# Convert JSON values into a string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
r = '{"available_sizes":[{"id":104682,"name":"40","preorder_only":false},{"id":104683,"name":"41","preorder_only":false},{"id":104684,"name":"42","preorder_only":false},{"id":104685,"name":"43","preorder_only":false},{"id":104687,"name":"45","preorder_only":false}]}'

data = json.loads(r)

for element in data: 
    for value in data['available_sizes']:
        print(value['name'])
```

At the moment this prints out the following:

```
40
41
42
43
45
```

How would I then use this data as a string? Below is the desired output.

```
Available sizes are 40, 41, 41, 43, 45
```

Comment: `', '.join([str(v['name']) for v in data['available_sizes']])`

Comment: Works a dream thank you - would you like to post as an asnwer so I can award it to you? @coldspeed

Comment: Sure, a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outermost loop is superfluous, since you only have a single key to iterate over.

Iterate over `data`, append your numbers to a list, and then call `str.join` at the end to efficiently join your strings together.

```
nums = []
for v in data['available_sizes']:
    nums.append(str(v['name']))  # v['name'] if it is already string

print(f'Available sizes are {', '.join(nums)}')
```

You can rewrite the loop using a list comprehension -

```
num_str = ', '.join([v['name'] for v in data['available_sizes']])
print(f'Available sizes are {num_str}')
```

For a primer on JSON data traversals, I recommend looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193502/access-a-particular-field-in-arbitrarily-nested-json-data/48193692#48193692).

Answer (score 0):

Use a for-comprehension to extract the size names, and then `str.join()` to add the comma separator:

```
import json

r = '{"available_sizes":[{"id":104682,"name":"40","preorder_only":false},{"id":104683,"name":"41","preorder_only":false},{"id":104684,"name":"42","preorder_only":false},{"id":104685,"name":"43","preorder_only":false},{"id":104687,"name":"45","preorder_only":false}]}'
data = json.loads(r)

# Extract the size names from the list of available sizes
size_names = [size_entry["name"] for size_entry in data["available_sizes"]]

# Join the sizes names as strings using a comma separator and print
sizes_string = ", ".join(size_names)
print("Available sizes are: " + sizes_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like that this is the out put that you want

```
import json

 r = '{"available_sizes":[{"id":104682,"name":"40","preorder_only":false},{"id":104683,"name":"41","preorder_only":false},{"id":104684,"name":"42","preorder_only":false},{"id":104685,"name":"43","preorder_only":false},{"id":104687,"name":"45","preorder_only":false}]}'

data = json.loads(r)

var = []

for element in data: 
    for value in data['available_sizes']:
        var.append(value['name'])
print( 'Availble size are %s' %(', '.join(var)))
```