# Python- Issue parsing multi-layered API JSON into CSV

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest, csv

I'm trying to parse the NIH grant `API` and am running into a complex layering issue. In the `JSON` output below, I've been able to navigate into the `"results"` section which contains all the fields I want, except some are layered within another dictionary. What I'm trying to do is get the `JSON` data within `"full_study_section"`, `"organization"`, and `"project_num_split"` to be in the same layer as `"appl_id"`, `"contact_pi_name"`, `"fiscal_year"`, and so forth. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193502/access-a-particular-field-in-arbitrarily-nested-json-data) was helpful but I'm not quite sure how to level the layers through iteration.

```
{
"meta":{
    "limit":25,
    "offset":0,
    "properties":{},
    "search_id":null,
    "sort_field":"project_start_date",
    "sort_order":"desc",
    "sorted_by_relevance":false,
    "total":78665
},
"results":[
    {
        "appl_id":10314644,
        "contact_pi_name":"BROCATO, EMILY ROSE",
        "fiscal_year":2021,
        "full_study_section":{
            "group_code":"32",
            "name":"Special Emphasis Panel[ZAA1 GG (32)]",
            "sra_designator_code":"GG",
            "sra_flex_code":"",
            "srg_code":"ZAA1",
            "srg_flex":""
        },
        "organization":{
            "city":null,
            "country":null,
            "dept_type":"PHARMACOLOGY",
            "external_org_id":353201,
            "fips_country_code":null,
            "org_city":"RICHMOND",
            "org_country":"UNITED STATES",
            "org_duns":[
                "105300446"
            ],
            "org_fips":"US",
            "org_ipf_code":"353201",
            "org_name":"VIRGINIA COMMONWEALTH UNIVERSITY",
            "org_state":"VA",
            "org_state_name":null,
            "org_zipcode":"232980568"
        },
        "project_end_date":null,
        "project_num":"1F31AA029259-01A1",
        "project_num_split":{
            "activity_code":"F31",
            "appl_type_code":"1",
            "full_support_year":"01A1",
            "ic_code":"AA",
            "serial_num":"029259",
            "suffix_code":"A1",
            "support_year":"01"
        },
        "project_start_date":"2022-03-07T05:00:00Z",
        "subproject_id":null
    },
```

Code:

```
import requests
import json
import csv


params = {
     "criteria":
     {
       "fiscal_years":[2021]
     },
     "include_fields": [
        "ApplId","ContactPiName","FiscalYear",
        "OrgCountry","AllText",
        "FullStudySection","Organization","ProjectEndDate",
        "ProjectNum","ProjectNumSplit","ProjectStartDate","SubprojectId"
     ],
     "offset":0,
     "limit":25,
     "sort_field":"project_start_date",
     "sort_order":"desc"
 }
response = requests.post("https://api.reporter.nih.gov/v2/projects/search", json = params)

#print(response.status_code)

#print(response.text)
     
resdecode = json.loads(response.text)

#print(json.dumps(resdecode, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ':')))

data = resdecode["results"]

#print(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ':')))

pns = resdecode["results"][0]["project_num_split"]

#print(json.dumps(pns, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ':')))

# for item in data:
#     appl_id = item.get("appl_id")
#     print(appl_id)        
    
writerr = csv.writer(open('C:/Users/nkmou/Desktop/Venture/Tech Opportunities/NIH.csv', 'w', newline = ''))   
    
count = 0

for row in resdecode:

      if count == 0:

              header = resdecode.keys()

              writerr.writerow(header)

              count += 1

      writerr.writerow(row)

writerr.close()
```

Comment: whats output you trying to get?

Comment: @rv.kvetch  What I'm trying to do is get the JSON data within "full_study_section", "organization", and "project_num_split" to be in the same layer as "appl_id", "contact_pi_name", "fiscal_year", and so forth. So that a CSV file has those headers on the same level.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move the items under full_study_section, organization and project_num_split to same level as appl_id, contact_pi_name and fiscal_year you will have to loop through each of the results and recreate those key value pairs for those three dicts and then remove the full_study_section, organization and project_num_split keys once done. Below code should work as you expected.

```
import requests
import json
import csv


params = {
     "criteria":
     {
       "fiscal_years":[2021]
     },
     "include_fields": [
        "ApplId","ContactPiName","FiscalYear",
        "OrgCountry","AllText",
        "FullStudySection","Organization","ProjectEndDate",
        "ProjectNum","ProjectNumSplit","ProjectStartDate","SubprojectId"
     ],
     "offset":0,
     "limit":25,
     "sort_field":"project_start_date",
     "sort_order":"desc"
 }
response = requests.post("https://api.reporter.nih.gov/v2/projects/search", json = params)

    
resdecode = json.loads(response.text)
data = resdecode["results"]


for item in data:
    x = ["full_study_section","organization","project_num_split"]
    for i in x:
        for key, value in item[i].items():
            item[key] = value
        del item[i]

with open('C:/Users/nkmou/Desktop/Venture/Tech Opportunities/NIH.csv', 'w', newline = '') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    count = 0
    for row in data:
        if count == 0:
            header = row.keys()
            writer.writerow(header)
            count =+ 1
        writer.writerow(row.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the items to the required level and remove the dict.

```
import json
import pprint

pp = pprint

file = open("test.json")
jsonData = json.load(file)

full_study_section = jsonData['results'][0]['full_study_section']
organization = jsonData['results'][0]['organization']
project_num_split = jsonData['results'][0]['project_num_split']

jsonData['results'][0].update(full_study_section)
jsonData['results'][0].update(project_num_split)
jsonData['results'][0].update(organization)

jsonData['results'][0].pop('full_study_section')
jsonData['results'][0].pop('project_num_split')
jsonData['results'][0].pop('organization')

pp.pprint(jsonData)
```

Output:

```
{u'meta': {u'limit': 25,
           u'offset': 0,
           u'properties': {},
           u'search_id': None,
           u'sort_field': u'project_start_date',
           u'sort_order': u'desc',
           u'sorted_by_relevance': False,
           u'total': 78665},
 u'results': [{u'activity_code': u'F31',
               u'appl_id': 10314644,
               u'appl_type_code': u'1',
               u'city': None,
               u'contact_pi_name': u'BROCATO, EMILY ROSE',
               u'country': None,
               u'dept_type': u'PHARMACOLOGY',
               u'external_org_id': 353201,
               u'fips_country_code': None,
               u'fiscal_year': 2021,
               u'full_support_year': u'01A1',
               u'group_code': u'32',
               u'ic_code': u'AA',
               u'name': u'Special Emphasis Panel[ZAA1 GG (32)]',
               u'org_city': u'RICHMOND',
               u'org_country': u'UNITED STATES',
               u'org_duns': [u'105300446'],
               u'org_fips': u'US',
               u'org_ipf_code': u'353201',
               u'org_name': u'VIRGINIA COMMONWEALTH UNIVERSITY',
               u'org_state': u'VA',
               u'org_state_name': None,
               u'org_zipcode': u'232980568',
               u'project_end_date': None,
               u'project_num': u'1F31AA029259-01A1',
               u'project_start_date': u'2022-03-07T05:00:00Z',
               u'serial_num': u'029259',
               u'sra_designator_code': u'GG',
               u'sra_flex_code': u'',
               u'srg_code': u'ZAA1',
               u'srg_flex': u'',
               u'subproject_id': None,
               u'suffix_code': u'A1',
               u'support_year': u'01'}]}
```