# Extract specific value from JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get all the websites from [this json file](https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list/blob/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json)

Unfortunately, when I use this code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list/blob/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json")
output = response.json()

# Extract specific node content.
print(output['website'])
```

I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dusandev/Desktop/StreamFlowWebTests/extract.py", line 5, in <module>
output = response.json()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", 
line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", 
line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
 File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", 
 line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: You should be using `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json` - i.e. raw view of the JSON. That said, you will get error with `output['website']` because it is deeply nested, not top level key.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193502/access-a-particular-field-in-arbitrarily-nested-json-data for accessing nested JSON data.

Comment: You will get a HTML with that link, As per the answer from @buran you should be calling the other link, and that should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `raw` data to get raw `json` and then iterate over '`tokens`' `attr` of the `response` object:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json")

output = response.json()
for i in output['tokens']:
    if i.get('extensions'):
        print(i.get('extensions').get('website'))
```

Comment: You can use `if extensions := i.get('extensions'):` and `print(extensions.get('website'))` to not perform search by key twice.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that the output can not be parsed as a json.

you have 2 options:

1. use "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json" instead-

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json")
output = response.json()
first_website = output["tokens"][0]["extensions"]["website"]

#all websites:

for token in output['tokens']:
    if extensions := token.get('extensions'): print(extensions.get('website'))

#output:
'https://www.angle.money'
```

2. you can parse it using `BeautifulSoup` - https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-python-using-beautiful-soup/

Comment: This is almost certainly not the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: This could be a comment to the question rather than the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The file https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list/blob/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json is not a json. Use https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json instead.

Comment: This could be a comment to the question rather than the answer.

Comment: @TonyMontana This is literallly a solution to the poster's problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the url https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list/blob/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json in a browser, you'll get a fully rendered web page. In order to get *just JSON* you need to use the "view raw" link. That winds up being

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json

You will then have several thousand elements in the array attached to the "tokens" key in the response dictionary. To get the website element you'll need to iterate through the list and look at the "extensions"

```
>>> output["tokens"][0]
{'chainId': 101, 'address': 'CbNYA9n3927uXUukee2Hf4tm3xxkffJPPZvGazc2EAH1', 'symbol': 'agEUR', 'name': 'agEUR (Wormhole)', 'decimals': 8, 'logoURI': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/main/assets/mainnet/CbNYA9n3927uXUukee2Hf4tm3xxkffJPPZvGazc2EAH1/logo.png', 'tags': ['ethereum', 'wrapped', 'wormhole'], 'extensions': {'address': '0x1a7e4e63778B4f12a199C062f3eFdD288afCBce8', 'assetContract': 'https://etherscan.io/address/0x1a7e4e63778B4f12a199C062f3eFdD288afCBce8', 'bridgeContract': 'https://etherscan.io/address/0x3ee18B2214AFF97000D974cf647E7C347E8fa585', 'coingeckoId': 'ageur', 'description': 'Angle is the first decentralized, capital efficient and over-collateralized stablecoin protocol', 'discord': 'https://discord.gg/z3kCpTaKMh', 'twitter': 'https://twitter.com/AngleProtocol', 'website': 'https://www.angle.money'}}

>>> output["tokens"][0]["extensions"]["website"]
'https://www.angle.money'
```