# How to read data from a list in a json object

Tags: python, json

I have JSON data that I need to read and then print:

```json
json_load =\
{"city": {"coord": {"lat": 52.2183, "lon": 6.8958},
          "country": "NL",
          "id": 2756071,
          "name": "Enschede",
          "population": 153655,
          "sunrise": 1656472443,
          "sunset": 1656532643,
          "timezone": 7200},
 "cnt": 40,
 "cod": "200",
 "list": [{"clouds": {"all": 50},
           "dt": 1656536400,
           "dt_txt": "2022-06-29 21:00:00",
           "main": {"feels_like": 295.23,
                    "grnd_level": 1007,
                    "humidity": 60,
                    "pressure": 1012,
                    "sea_level": 1012,
                    "temp": 295.38,
                    "temp_kf": 2.77,
                    "temp_max": 295.38,
                    "temp_min": 292.61},
           "pop": 0,
           "sys": {"pod": "n"},
           "visibility": 10000,
           "weather": [{"description": "scattered clouds",
                        "icon": "03n",
                        "id": 802,
                        "main": "Clouds"}],
           "wind": {"deg": 99, "gust": 1.93, "speed": 1.9}}]}
```

Now I want to read: `feels_like`, `temp`, etc.
I can read the first part on top with:

```
print(json_load['city']['coord'])
```

But if I want to read:

```
print(json_load['list']['main'])
```

I get a keyword error 0.

Comment: `json_load['list']` is a list, so you need to get the first element: `print(json_load['list'][0]['main'])`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193502/access-a-particular-field-in-arbitrarily-nested-json-data

Answer (score 3):

Since `json_load['list']` *is* a list, you have to use indices to access the items in it. Here's how to get the contents of the first (zeroth) element of it:

```
print(json_load['list'][0]['main']['feels_like'])  # -> 295.23
print(json_load['list'][0]['main']['temp'])  # -> 295.38
```