# how to grep the word within the {...} using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, unix

i would like to grep the only value: "INC1301724" from the "display_value":"INC1301724", from the text file: Response.txt below:

```
print('Response after Snow ticket update : '+response.text)
```

value of response.text is:

```
{"import_set":"ISET1677878","staging_table":"u_incident_create_import","result":[{"transform_map":"Incident Create Import","table":"incident","display_name":"number","display_value":"INC1301724","record_link":"https://example.com/api/now/table/incident/04331234rfgthyjjkkkkllljhfdd","status":"inserted","sys_id":"01234567890"}]}
```

Comment: You mean you're executing the python script and piping it to grep?

Comment: `response.text` looks like JSON. So remove `Response after Snow ticket update :` from the beginning, then use `jq` to parse it rather than `grep`.

Comment: [How can I access the nested data in this complex JSON, which includes another JSON document as one of the strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48193502)

Comment: What is `response`? Is it the return value of a `requests.get` call? Post your whole code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with shell or unix

Comment: why not just `response.json()["result"][0]["display_value"]`?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to search every line for "display_value" then cut the substring with search about index of '"' :
[this is image of the Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJRy7.png)

```
with open('response.txt') as file:
for line in file:
    String_Line=line.rstrip()
    if "display_value" in String_Line:
        index1 = String_Line.find ( 'display_value":' )
        Newstring=String_Line[index1+16:]
        print(Newstring)
        new_index_1 = Newstring.find('"')
        print(new_index_1)
        your_string=Newstring[:new_index_1]
        print(your_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json`:

```
json.loads('{"import_set":"ISET1677878","staging_table":"u_incident_create_import","result":[{"transform_map":"Incident Create Import","table":"incident","display_name":"number","display_value":"INC1301724","record_link":"https://example.com/api/now/table/incident/04331234rfgthyjjkkkkllljhfdd","status":"inserted","sys_id":"01234567890"}]}')["result"][0]["display_value"]
```