# How to get a value in the nested JSON output?

Tags: python, json

I'm new to python. I have an JSON output nd get specific values from it. Can someone please help me to get the specific value

```
{"ABCDE": [{"Title": "Country Manager", "Name": "xxx yyy", "Office": "123-456-1234", "Cell": "xxx-xxx-xxxx", "Email": "abc@abc.com"}, {"Title": "Regional Manager", "Name": "abc redsbj", "Office": "yyy-yyy-yyyy", "Cell": "eee-eee-eeee", "Email": "xyz@xyz.com"}, {"Title": "General Manager", "Name": "Xyz whatever", "Office": "xxx-xxx-xxxx", "Cell": "xxx-xxx-xxxx", "Email": "whatever@whatever.com"}, {"Title": "General Manager - Regional", "Name": "whatever name", "Office": "www-www-wwww", "Cell": "rrr-rrr-rrrr", "Email": "cde@cde.comm"}], "VWXYZ": [{"Title": "Country Manager", "Name": "nnn nnnnnnn", "Office": "123-123-1234", "Work Cell": NaN, "Email": abd@anbd.com}, {"Title": "Regional Manager", "Name": "jane doe", "Office": "1234567890", "Work Cell": "1231231234", "Email": "jane@doe.com"}, {"Title": "General Manager", "Name": "Doe Jane", "Office": "1232343456", "Work Cell": "9098981234", "Email": "doe@jane.com"}]}
```

## output expected

{'ABCDE':['General Manager':Xyz whatever', 'Office': 'xxx-xxx-xxxx', 'Cell': 'xxx-xxx-xxxx', 'Email': 'whatever@whatever.com'], 'VWXYZ':['General Manager':'Doe Jane', 'Office': '1232343456', 'Work Cell': '9098981234', 'Email': 'doe@jane.com']}

```
with open(htmlFilePath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    siteCode = str(file_name)[:3]       
    
    tables = pd.read_html(file)       
    df = tables[1]        
    if df.columns[0] != "Title":
        df.columns = df.iloc[0]            
        df = df[1:]            
        df = df.reset_index(drop=True)        
    atoDataDict[key] = df.to_dict("records")
```

jsonOutput = json.dumps(atoDataDict)

Comment: Please post the code that your tried

Comment: Seems like a question that was previously asked, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129652/accessing-json-elements, unless you have something more specific that is not covered there.

Comment: Can you fix your input data and your output data so that they are valid?

Comment: The previous post looks like same but my key value is changing from one to another. So not sure how to use the same key reference in my code.

from the old post - the['data' is same but mine's changing
"print wjdata['data']['current_condition'][0]['temp_C']"

Comment: The input dats is exactly what I got from after converting to json using json dumps. For the output, I just need "key" and general manager contact details.

Comment: There is no chance that `json.dumps()` produce the key value pair `("Email", abd@anbd.com)`

Comment: Sorry but it did. I'm parsing HTML files using the Pandas and get that as the output. 

I've added the parsing code to the original post for your reference. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you correct your inputs and outputs, I believe you are looking to do something like:

```py
data_out = {}
for key, value in data_in.items():
    data_out[key] = []
    for item in value:
        if not item["Title"] == "General Manager":
            continue

        item["General Manager"] = item["Name"]
        del item["Title"]
        del item["Name"]
        data_out[key].append(item)
```

Comment: The above worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you might reformat you data
data = {
'ABCDE': {
'General Manager': 'Xyz whatever',
'Office': 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
'Cell': 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
'Email': 'whatever@whatever.com'
},
'VWXYZ': {
'General Manager': 'Doe Jane',
'Office': '1232343456',
'Work Cell': '9098981234',
'Email': 'doe@jane.com'
}
}
and then you can access specific value you want, for example
manager_abcde = data['ABCDE']['General Manager']

Comment: Thank you. But how can I reformat it? Sorry I'm new to this and need help.